# maven resource filtering: insert a complete file into a property

Tags: java, maven

I want to make simple templating during `mvn build`:

My resource has a `${variable}`, filtering is enabled in `pom.xml`.

How can I substitute the `${variable}` with a complete file?

**UPDATE: I am looking for something like http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadfile.html in maven**

Comment: May be you can elaborate a little bit more so we can help better with more details what you like to achieve etc.

Comment: An answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289425/how-to-retrieve-information-from-antrun-back-to-maven

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for such purposes is the [templating-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/templating-maven-plugin/).

Comment: If I combine AntRun-Plugin with Ant's LoadFile task, can I access the the loaded property later in my maven build? I am quite restricted in adding new plugins to the build.

Comment: Which kind of properties would you like to access? BTW: Using AntRun plugin is better than templating-maven-plugin ? Hm..strange.

Comment: I want to inject a javascript into a html file.

Comment: but you did not answer the question in the comment above !? is the property from the loadfile task then only available in the execution of the antrun-plugin?

Comment: Put the javascript into an appropriate folder and load it via script tag. Otherwise you can use the templating-maven-plugin for such purposes as well. Only change the source- and target folder of the plugin.

Comment: doh! Fact is, I cannot change the html-head, only the body. But <script src=...> also works in the body. stupid me.